# Start a task if Disk space Utilization is free space is below 25%

Tags: powershell

I have a program running that creates temp files if the disk utilization is less than 25 GB it needs to restart a service.
In a Nutshell  i have done this with no success.

```
if( (get-item C:\).length -gt 25GB)
{
 restart-service "someservice"
}
else{ donothing}
```

I believe it should be something like this

```
if( get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DeviceID='C:'"|select freespace.length -gt 25GB)
{
 restart-service "someservice"
}
else{ donothing}
```

can Any one offer some help thanks in advance

Comment: `if( (get-item C:\).length -gt 25GB)` -> "if the list of files in the root of my C drive has more than twenty five billion filenames in it, then..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got something like this working i will try all.
how to make the task always running?

```
if (( (Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT FreeSpace FROM Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE DeviceID = 'C:'").FreeSpace / 1GB ) -lt 20)
    {
      restart-service "someservive"
    } 
    else{write-host "wow" -f red}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
if( (get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -Filter "DeviceID='C:'").freespace -lt 25GB) {
    restart-service "someservice"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
if ((Get-Volume -DriveLetter 'C').SizeRemaining -lt 25GB)
{
    Restart-Service "someservice"
}
```

Probably needs PowerShell 4, and 'run as administrator'